# how to use Rsync to synchronize data from multiple servers to one server in a folder

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm using GlusterFS to connect 5 servers to be a big storage, now i want to transfer the data on these 5 servers to other 5 servers and i'm thinking about use Rsync to do this. It's easier if i use only one server to run command Rsync to a new server (connected by glusterfs) but the speed will be really slow so i want to use old 5 servers transfer data to 5 new servers that makes the speed faster x5 times. Is there any way to do that with Rsync or any other ways to do this?

Comment: Split it into five sets? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154768/rsync-split-source-as-multiple-sets

Comment: This could use some clarity and detail. Are the five new nodes running glusterfs servers/bricks, or are you moving to something else? Are you wanting to achieve a migration and service transition after this transfer, or are you going to be continually synchronizing these volumes?  Finally, what is this for?

Comment: @Spooler The five new nodes running glusterfs (everything on new nodes are the same as the old nodes) And my purpose is move all of my data from old DC to new DC and i'm searching for a fastest way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

GlusterFS has geoclustering abilities that internally use rsync to do what you describe wanting to do.

https://docs.gluster.org/en/v3/Administrator%20Guide/Geo%20Replication/

Comment: suppose I use geo-replication, after all data synced and I need to remove the Master node so the Slave one can be a new master node? i mean can I continue write new data directly to Slave?